# Adding UIActivityIndicator to Default.png image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

By naming an image `Default.png` it will show up when the application launches. But when the application launch i need to show a `UIActivityIndicator` on the `Default.png`. How can i do this programatically ?

Comment: Pretty sure you just make your `onApplicationLaunchWithSettings` method real short, make it load a view that has the same bgimage, which does all the grunt work of loading resources, while displaying the spinner.  (I have never actually done this but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new View.
Make it the root controller to your app delegate window object.

In its xib file add the default.png as its background..
In you code when view loads.spin the activity ..and then load the new view(main app) by doing `performselector: withObject: afterDelay:` method.

This way when your app actually launches.. you can show the activity for as much time and load the app.
There is no way you can do any sort of loading(custom animation) until your app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method is called..

Comment: If i have an image called default.png then it will load during startup without the activityIndicator. So should i have to rename it ? And `performselector: withObject: afterDelay:` should be added to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` event ?

Comment: no..you do not rename it.. just add a image view in the new view..and then set it to default.png in the interface builder..then in your new view..do the performselector in the view did load..

Comment: One more thing, Should i call this viewController (the one which contains the imageview (deafult.png) and the activityindicator) in the  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?

Comment: yes.. there will be lines you can check of  self.window.rootViewController = something.. change something to your new view.